# how to check if indexOf is even or odd?

Tags: javascript

I want to add a style to odd and even elements of this array.

```
 let myArr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
const body1 = document.body;

let i = 0;

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  i++;
  let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.textContent = myArr[i];
  body1.appendChild(newDiv);
});
```

Comment: You write the item that you're searching for. `arr.indexOf("a")`

Comment: But I don't want to repeat every item. Is it possible to loop through the array and find out?

Comment: You better clarify your question because right now nothing it in suggests the need for a loop.

Comment: If you loop through the array, you don't need `indexOf`. The loop contains the indexes.

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` you just test if `i` is even or odd.

Comment: for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    i % 2 == 0 ? arr[i].style.backgroundColor = "green" : arr[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}    This is what I want to achieve, but I know the syntax is faulty.

Comment: The items in the array are strings, not DOM elements. Do you want to check the array index is odd / even or that the array item is odd / even?

Comment: I want to check their index and style them differently. BTW why the first element is not displayed when I click?

Comment: Because you increase `i` at the start of the event listener, so `i` always starts at `1`

Comment: How can I fix that too?

Comment: Do `i++` at the end of the event listener, not the start. The best option is to loop through the array anyway, unless you really want the button click to trigger this stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to loop through the array to get the index. Using that, you can do the modulus check to see if it's even or odd and do something with the div before pushing it on to the body.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let myArr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
  const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
  const body1 = document.body;

  // Start at 1 to avoid any + 1 in the modulus check
  for(let i = 1; i <= myArr.length; i++) {
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.style.width = '100px'
    newDiv.style.height = '100px'
    newDiv.style.margin = '5px'
    newDiv.style.color = 'white'
    // - 1 because we start the loop at 1 and indexes start at 0 in JS
    newDiv.textContent = myArr[i - 1]; 

    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      newDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
      newDiv.style.float = 'right'
    } else {
      newDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
      newDiv.style.float = 'left'
    }
    body1.appendChild(newDiv);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest and most efficient way of determining if a number is even or odd:

```
number & 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the items in the array are DOM elements? So you maybe want to do something like this:

```js
arr.forEach((item, index) => {
 if (index % 2 == 0) {
   // Even
   item.style = ...;
   // or maybe
   item.className = ...;
 } else {
   // Same here, apply whatever style/class you want to use for the odd elements.
      }
});
```

Comment: myArr.forEach((item, index) => {
if (index % 2 == 0) {
item.style.color = "red";
} else {
item.style.color = "blue";
}
}); Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "color", item.style is undefined

Answer (score -1):

I believe this will work for you:

```js
var Arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
for (i=0; i<Arr.length; i++){
    var OddOrEven = (i % 2) ? "Even" : "Odd";
    if (OddOrEven=="Odd"){
        // Do Stuff For Odd
    } else {
        // Do Stuff For Even
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't take someone elses answer and edit your answer to include it (referring to the copy of @php_nub_qq's answer)

Comment: It's not, it's just not a noble thing to do. Btw your edit won't work as it's backwards. You want `i % 2 === 0`

Comment: The code worked in the console. I tested it out. I assume ["Odd", "Even", "Odd", "Even"] as the layout incase that was the concern, @CarlMarkham

Comment: Try `2 % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd'`, it will say odd. 2 is not odd though...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238717/discussion-between-super-buff-meatballs-and-carl-markham).